# Nest an iterator of Python context managers in "with"

Tags: python, iterator, nested, contextmanager

I have an iterator that returns context managers.

I want a pythonic `with` statement, that emulates the behaviour of several nested `with` statements, one for each context manager returned by the iterator.

One could say, I want a generalisation of the (deprecated) `contextlib.nested` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contextlib.nested` has two major problems that caused it to be deprecated.

1. first problem is that *inner* context managers might raise Exceptions during `__init__` or `__new__`, and these exceptions would cause the whole with statement to abort without calling `__exit__` of the outer manager.
2. The second problem is more complicated. If one of the inner managers raises an exception and one of the outer managers catches it by returning `True` in `__exit__`, the block should still be executed. But in the implementation of `nested`, it just raises a `RuntimeError` without executing the block. This problem probably requires a total rewrite of `nested`.

But it is possible to solve the *first* problem by just removing one `*` in the definition of `nested`!
This changes the behaviour such that `nested` doesn't accept argument lists anymore (which isn't useful anyway because `with` can handle that already) but only an iterator. I therefore call the new version "`iter_nested`".
The user can then define an iterator that instantiates the context managers during iteration.

An example with a generator:

```
def contexts():
    yield MyContext1()
    yield MyContext2()

with iter_nested(contexts()) as contexts:
    do_stuff(contexts[0])
    do_other_stuff(contexts[1])
```

The difference between the codes of the original and my changed version of `nested` is here:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
--- def nested(*managers):
+++ def iter_nested(mgr_iterator):
    --- #comments & deprecation warning
    exits = []
    vars = []
    --- exc = (None, None, None)
    +++ exc = None # Python 3
    try:
        --- for mgr in managers:
        +++ for mgr in mgr_iterator:
            exit = mgr.__exit__
            enter = mgr.__enter__
            vars.append(enter())
            exits.append(exit)
        yield vars
# All of the following is new and fit for Python 3
except Exception as exception:
    exc = exception
    exc_tuple = (type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__)
else:
    exc_tuple = (None, None, None)
finally:
    while exits:
        exit = exits.pop()
        try:
            if exit(*exc_tuple):
                exc = None
                exc_tuple = (None, None, None)
        except Exception as exception:
            exception.__context__ = exc
            exc = exception
            exc_tuple = (type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__)
    if exc:
        raise exc
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested):

> Developers that need to support nesting of a variable number of context managers can either use the `warnings` module to suppress the `DeprecationWarning` raised by [`contextlib.nested`] or else use this function as a model for an application specific implementation.

The difficult thing about handling multiple context managers is that they interact non-trivially: for example, you might `__enter__` the first then raise an exception in `__enter__`ing the second. These sort of edge cases are precisely what caused `nested` to be deprecated. If you want to support them, you will have to think very carefully about how you write your code. You may wish to read [PEP-0343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) for ideas.

Comment: That's not a complete answer, but now I know what to take care of when I write it!

Answer (score 0):

This implementation - or something more or less like this, should make what the late contextçlib.nested used to do, but taking care of the already entered contexts if an exception is raised when entering a new context.

Contexts can be passed to it either as a context-protocol  object, or as a tuple,
where the first member is a called object that will be called with the remainder of the tuple as parameters, in a managed environment:

```
import sys
import traceback


class NestContext(object):
    def __init__(self, *objects):
        self.objects = objects
    def __enter__(self):
        self.contexts = []
        for obj in self.objects:
            if isinstance(obj, tuple):
                try:
                    obj = obj[0](*obj[1:])
                except Exception, error:
                    self.__exit__(type(error), error, sys.exc_info()[2])
                    raise
            try:
                context = obj.__enter__()
            except Exception, error:
                self.__exit__(type(error), error, sys.exc_info()[2])
                raise   
            self.contexts.append(context)
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        for context in self.contexts:
            yield context

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        for context in reversed(self.contexts):
            try:
                context.__exit__(*args)
            except Exception, error:
                sys.stderr.write(str(error))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # example uasage

    class PlainContext(object):
        counter  = 0
        def __enter__(self):
            self.counter = self.__class__.counter
            print self.counter
            self.__class__.counter += 1
            return self
        def __exit__(self, *args):
            print "exiting %d" % self.counter

    with NestContext(*((PlainContext,) for i in range(10))) as all_contexts:
        print tuple(all_contexts)
```

Comment: There are a number of small problems with your implementation.

So, for example `self.contexts.append(context)` is not what we want, we need `self.contexts.append(obj)`. Also, `__enter__` should return `self.contexts` and not `self`.

Also, your except clauses are deprecated, it should better be `except Exception as error:`

Comment: If `__enter__` of any context manager raises an exception, then it is already handled as expected by the deprecated `nested` function. This is not the problem. The two problems are: `__init__` and `__new__` of a context manager raising exceptions (which is also solved by `nested` if the iterator instantiates the managers on iteration) and some other problem I don't fully understand, described in the documentation as pointed out by katrielalex.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question but I stumbled upon it.  One solution now is to use [contextlib.ExitStack()](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack):

```
with contextlib.ExitStack() as exit_stack:
    for cm in my_context_manager_iterator:
        exit_stack.enter_context(cm)
    # we are now within those contexts... do more things
```

It handles the problems mentioned in other answers.  If entering one context manager fails, the others you have already entered will be exited properly.

For async usage there is also `AsyncExitStack` with `enter_async_context()`